# Find the page template of the previous page

Tags: page-template

I am am working on a listing type theme and have a search results page that take people to a more details page. I also have links throughout the site that will also take visitors straight to the more details page.

On the more details page I would like to display a 'Back to search results' link but only if the user came from the search results page.

The only way I can think to do this is to get the page template of the previous page search-results.php and use that as the criteria for displaying the link.

Is there a way to get the page template of the previous page, or any other way to achieve this?

Comment: This is not a WordPress issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165975/determining-referer-in-php

Comment: @s_ha_dum But that does not get me the page template name which I believe is specific to WordPress.

Comment: The idea that you need the page template is incorrect. You need an identifier for the search page which you would pass via the URL (of check the `$_REQUEST` referrer.

Comment: That works but is not the best way to do it.

Comment: Actually, passing an identifier is the most reliable way to do it, but suit yourself.

Comment: @s_ha_dum I normally do suit myself usually with a single breasted jacket, matching trousers, and a white or blue shirt, sometimes if its cold I wear a waistcoat. But I don't understand what this as to do with the question or is it some kind of joke?

Comment: No joke. "suit yourself" is a colloquialism. It means "your choice". The accepted answer will break under some circumstances. Passing an identifier is more reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `wp_get_referer();` to get a URL of previous page from where user came. Then get the last slug part of the URL. Then compare if the slug matches with slug of your custom search-result page template. Then you can decide whether to show or not to show 'Back to search results' link. Please try below code and feel free to update as intended:

```
<?php 

    $ref_url = wp_get_referer();

    $results = explode('/', trim($ref_url,'/'));

    if(count($results) > 0){
        //get the last record
        $last_word = $results[count($results) - 1];
    }

    if ( $last_word == "about" )
        echo "<a href='$ref_url'>Back to search results</a>";

?>
```

Comment: This will break with some permalink structures.

Comment: Yes. I have assumed pretty permalinks are active.

Comment: It is possible (not from the backend without a plugin) to change page permalink structure too so it isn't just a matter of having pretty permalinks enabled or disabled. It is a condition that should be noted.

Comment: I have used a part of the search string to test if the visitor came from a search page, is that what you meant by identifier?